# JSONata Node-RED node. Where to find

Tags: node-red, jsonata

I've just watched this Youtube video by Andrew Coleman of IBM about JSONata https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZRtlkIj0uDY

In the video Andrew previews a instance of Node-RED he is running that contains a JSONata node.

I have searched high and low for this JSONata node as I would really like to put it to use in some of my more complex flows that define my external API and WebHook end points.

I did find this `node-red-contrib-tgr-jsonata` in the pallet options but it isn't the same one and I can't get this to work in a usable way.

Does anybody know where I can download the JSONata node shown in this video ??

Comment: Edit the link to the youtube video to point to the place where the Node-RED node is mentioned (I'm not scrolling through an hour long video to find it)

Comment: @hardillb Sorry yes, it's at time code 24.00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't need a dedicated jsonata node as the core Change node supports using a JSONata expression - select the "expression" type when configuring the properties to set.

Comment: Hi @knolleary I already do this in places but was hoping that somebody knows where that dedicated JSONata node can be downloaded / installed from as it would help visually while looking at the flows.

Comment: I don't think Andrew ever published it once we had integrated jsonata into the core nodes.